# Asyncio: order loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-asyncio

I would like to know how can I order a program like this:

```
import asyncio


async def multi_coro():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(coro('5'))
        print('3-')
        tg.create_task(coro('6'))
        print('4-')


async def coro(i):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)
    print(i)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(multi_coro())
        print('1-')
        tg.create_task(coro('7'))
        print('2-')
    print('8-')


asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(main())
```

My goal is to get this return:

```
1-
2-
3-
4-
5
6
7
5
6
7
8-
```

But the return is:

```
1-
2-
3-
4-
7
5
6
7
5
6
8-
```

In use asyncio.gather(), the result is like TaskGroup.

```
async def gather():
    print('3-')
    await asyncio.gather(*[coro('4'), coro('5')])
    print('6-')
```

So I would like to know how can I do to call tasks group in multi_coro before to call the second task in the main()

Edit:

```
import asyncio


async def another_coro(i):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)


async def coro(i, tg):
    if i == 1:
        tg.create_task(another_coro(i * 10))
        tg.create_task(another_coro(i * 100))
    else:
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for i in range(0, 3):
            tg.create_task(coro(i, tg))


asyncio.run(main())
```

printing is 0 => 2 => 10 => 100

But I would a method to get 0 => 10 => 100 => ... No matter what the sequence is, it is the result 10 and 100 directly after 0 that is sought.

Comment: So quick question, is async required? Cause async does not guarantee the order by which code is run.

Comment: `multi_coro` and `coro` are interwined.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide yes async is required. coro represents a function with async interaction(HTTP requests).

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes. It's not an error, I would like to prioritized multi_coro execution

Comment: So are you just wanting `multi_coro` to complete first before calling `coro`? Or another way is that you want to call a coroutine and once its finished call the second coroutine?

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide In my case, I had multiple similar coroutines(here 'coro') which need to call two others coroutines if a condition is verified(here 'multi_coro'). This is what I wanted to replicate in the simple example above. 
So I would like to iterate my loop with similar coroutines('coro'). And if I want to start two others coroutines('multi_coro') in a couritine('coro'). I would like to add in my loop the new coroutines created. Without waiting for it to execute a first time completely my loop. Is it more understandable?

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide I can give you another more complete example to illustrate my point if needed!

Comment: If you dont await a task there is no guarantee on order of completion. Is there a reason you dont want to await a task?

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide 
I edited my post to illustrate my point more simply with code.
Yes there is a reason, I have dozens or even hundreds of simple tasks. And if a condition is verified in a simple task, I would like to be able to immediately schedule the launch of two coroutines that launch a http request. Once the two coroutines have initiated the request and are waiting. I don't care if I have to continue my loop or start over. It's really the immediate call that interests me. Without having to wait for my XXX other coroutines to initialize.

Comment: If you want 10 & 100 to come after 1 but before 2 everytime then you have to await. If all you do is create a task and move on then there is no way to know which one python will run or which one will complete first. You can create the two tasks then await then once finished move on to the next set. That will get you the result your looking for

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Great, your answer sounds interesting but I can't reproduce it. I don't care if it's 10 => 100 or 100 => 10. As long as they are executed immediately after 1 and thus before 2. Can you write the code portion to show me. Or explain me that they functions used to arrive to write an answer. Please.

Answer (score 1):

The thing there is that your first task calling `multi_coro` itself won't run until your code allows the asyncio loop to run, inside your `main` code. Once it is awaited, as the TaskGroup it creates is exited before the co-routine finishes, the sub-coros it creates will also run.

Inserting a `await asyncio.sleep(0)` creating the coro that will print `7` would work: but that would not be deterministic - the flow passes to the event loop, that will take the opportunity to step through existing tasks - but that behavior is implementation dependant.

*exiting* the task group and entering another, on the other hand, yes, will await all existing tasks created in that group, and will be a reliable behavior:

```
 import asyncio


async def multi_coro():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(coro('5'))
        print('3-')
        tg.create_task(coro('6'))
        print('4-')


async def coro(i):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)
    print(i)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(multi_coro())
        print('1-')
    # here we end a task group, forcing the created tasks
    # to run up to completion. 
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(coro('7'))
        print('2-')
    print('8-')
```

This won't print your desired order - it is deterministically "3 4 (sync) 5 6 5 6 (both tasks in first group, alternating as they find the sleep (.1) 1 2 (sync) 7 7 (new task) 8 (sync) " - but understanding this, you have the keys to enforce the particular order you need.

Keep in mind a task group is a normal object you can just pass along as a parameter - so, instead of creating a new task group inside "multi_coro" you can pass it `tg`  as an argument, and the loop will await for any tasks it creates there along with others:

```
import asyncio


async def multi_coro(tg):
    tg.create_task(coro('5'))
    print('3-')
    tg.create_task(coro('6'))
    print('4-')


async def coro(i):
    print(i)
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)
    print(i)


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(multi_coro(tg))
        tg.create_task(coro(7))

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        print('1-')
        tg.create_task(coro('8'))
        print('2-')
    print('9-')


asyncio.run(main())
```

printing:

```
3-
4-
7
5
6
7
5
6
1-
2-
8
8
9-
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanation. In my case, I had multiple similar coroutines(here 'coro') which need to call two others coroutines if a condition is verified(here 'multi_coro'). This is what I wanted to replicate in the simple example above. So I would like to iterate my loop with similar coroutines('coro'). And if I want to start two others coroutines('multi_coro') in a couritine('coro'). I would like to add in my loop the new coroutines created. Without waiting for it to execute a first time completely my loop.

Comment: With your explanations, I could iterate my coroutines and if my condition is fulfilled, I break the group of tasks to execute the couroutines as fast as possible. Then recreate my tasks and start the scenario again. But isn't there a cleaner way than breaking the task group to schedule the execution of a task group immediately?
I can give you another more complete example to illustrate my point if needed!

Comment: as for breaking a group of tasks, fixing something and rescheduling them - something there smells like you need `asyncio.wait` - which can "pause" a set of tasks  on an exception or on a timeout: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait - maybe there is some possible clever interation possible with task groups + asyncio.wait . feel free to write another question, if needed, and ping me (e-mail on profile)

Comment: Hello, I have sent you an email